# Download image with Zend - PHP header: wrong file format

Tags: php, header, download

First of all, I know this question has already been asked but I can't solve it anyway.
I need to set a link to download images(jpg).
I read various posts found here and with google but it's always the same results:
I can download the file but it's still the same error. The jpeg format is not correct.

> Erreur d'interprétation du fichier
>   d'image JPEG (Not a JPEG file: starts
>   with 0x0a 0x20)

When I test this in a file without a controller, it's ok but the script in a controller doesn't work.

Here is the code for tests:

```
 $file = '{document_root}/www/themes/default/images/common/background1.jpg';

if (file_exists($file))
{
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));

    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

This code works in a simple php file. I download the picture and can open it.
But within my controller, the file is not good.

I found that the tag ?> can add spaces but my controllers doesn't have this closing tag.
I've tested some code with the Zend objects found in various posts but it's the same error.

I've tried various way to read the file (file_get_content(), fread() ...) with the same result.
I assume there's something wrong with my Zend controller.

I'm now testing my file according to this post:
[php file download: strange http header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359433/php-file-download-strange-http-header)

Any clue will be really appreciated.
Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

[EDIT: 21/06/2011 - 6h38]
Here is the code of the action

```
public function downloadAction()
{
    $this->view->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    $img = $this->_getParam('img');

    // Process the file
    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
    $width  = $config->catalog->image->original->maxWidth;
    $height = $config->catalog->image->original->maxHeight;

    $prefix = $width . 'x' . $height . '_';
    $filename  = $prefix . $img;
    $file = Zend_Registry::get('document_root') . '/data/images/catalog/products/' . $this->_getParam('pid') .'/'. $filename;

    if (file_exists($file))
    {
        $this->getResponse()
         ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$filename)
         ->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
         ->setHeader('Content-Length', filesize($file))
         ->setHeader('Content-type', 'image/jpeg');

        $this->getResponse()->sendHeaders();

        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }

}
```

This action is not called directly. I test if a parameter exists in the url. 
If true then from the listAction, I call the downloadAction().
I've tried to disable the view and layout in both action but there's some html rendered.

Comment: Did you make sure to turn the outer layout off for the rendering of this action?

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is what I have to disable layout and view: // Disable view and layout rendering
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();

Comment: I opened the downloaded file with Bless (hex editor) and the file contains html code. It's the part of my template containing the view. I'm now looking for the way to remove this.

Comment: Can you show the code of the entire action? Although not part of your issue, the Content-type for jpg is not `application/octet-stream` but `image/jpeg`

Comment: I would probably [create a custom context](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.custom) if its something you are going to be using often...

Comment: @datasage: I tried both content-type and with the same results. I set image/jpeg in the latest tests. For the code, I edited the first post. My problem is now more simple. I disabled the view/layout but there's some html code rendered. @prodigitalson: I will try this today, it seems to be the good way to do. I just have to learn how it works. I'm quite a begginer with Zend.  Thank you everybody. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: What is the html being generated? Perhaps rendering it will show your application is throwing an exception?

Comment: @Dickie: My app has a template to display the blocks I've created. Each block is a module view. The html rendered is the skeleton containing these blocks and to links "hardcoded". If I don't use the headers, it displays the links but there's no data from views and no CSS, js...

Comment: Because of our templates system, I always have some html rendered before the action is called. So I do some tests and if the user clicks the download link then I call the download action before rendering anything. `$this->action('download', 'index', 'catalog', array('img' => $img, 'pid' => $pid));
        exit;` But I still have 2 dots and 15 whites spaces at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem sending content after decrypt file's content.
0x0a means new line. You probably have some new line after the ?> tag in some included class.
Put

```
ob_clean(); 
flush();
```

before

```
readfile($file);
```

something like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean(); 
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

This work out fine for me. Hope it helps.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I codeing working zend framework :)

```
    public function dowloadfileAction(){
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    if ($this->_user->isUserLogin()) { 
        $path_file = 'public/uploads/file/';
        $filename  = $this->_getParam('file');; // of course find the exact filename....
        $file = $path_file.$filename; 
        //zfdebug(mime_content_type($file)); die();
        if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Cache-Control: private', false); // required for certain browsers 
        header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($file));
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. basename($file) . '";');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        }else{
            echo "File does not exist";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Please Login";
    }    
    exit;       
}
```